# django-csrf protection on ajax post

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am working on django 1.7 and python 2.7. To prevent csrf attack on ajax post request i have added csrf token in ajax header before send.
In views i have added csrf_protect decorator to check the token. Everything is working fine in this scenario. But In my project this function in views.py is being called internally in other views where i haven't implemented csrf token, this causing 403 error.So what i want to do is only when there is ajax post call have to check csrf_protect decorator. Every other calls can neglect.

```
def check_token(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.is_ajax():
                return csrf_protect(func(request,*args, **kwargs))
            return func(request,*args, **kwargs )
        return wrapper

@check_token
def myViews(request,mob,id):
"""function starts here"""
```

Comment: what is not working exactly with your current code as posted here?

Comment: @dirkgroten my intention was to make myViews function unprotected if its is called othere than ajax post. But some other view calling this function which is also getting blocked by decorator.

Comment: I understand the intention but your wrapper is checking `request.is_ajax()` that should take care of it. What's not working?

Comment: unfortunately csrf_protect is blocking 403 every requests. when i remove my custom decor its not giving 403

Comment: are the other views calling this view passing along the request object being called themselves in an ajax request? Then obviously your wrapper cannot work.

Comment: But to be honest, calling a view from another view is not really how you should do this kind of functionality. Create a separate function that is called by your protected view and your other views.

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator is equivalent to

```
myViews = check_token(myViews)
```

You could apply it manually to a new name:

```
def unprotected_view(request,mob,id):
    """function starts here"""
    ...

protected_view = check_token(unprotected_view)
```

Now you have a decorated and a non-decorated name for it.

Comment: This solution and @check_token are same, isn't it? My issue is its not working. Need your suggestion to make it work. Thanks

Comment: it's not the same solution. When you call your view from inside other views, use `unprotected_view`, in your urls use `protected_view` so ajax calls get the wrapped one.

Answer (score 1):

Calling views from within other views is not really what Django views are supposed to do. If you have some generic functionality to craft a response, make that a separate function. Then let your protected view call that function and your other views call it as well:

```
@csrf_protect
def my_view(request, mob, id):
     return craft_generic_response(request, mob, id)

def craft_generic_response(request, mob, id)
     # do stuff to create response
     return response

def another_view(request, mob, id):
     # do stuff
     response = craft_generic_response(**kwargs)
     # do more stuff
```